Smallest number of tacks Zach needs
Consider:
Zach wants to hang four equal sized square pictures on her wall but she has to use the absolute minimum number of tacks to hang them. Zach insists that she must put one tack in each corner of each photo. What is the smallest number of tacks Zack needs?
To me, shouldn't the answer be 4? We can place the 4 pictures over one another and use 4 tacks? However, the answer is 9? Assuming, the question maker wanted all 4 pictures to be seen, 9 makes sense.
Now my motivation for this post is to generalise this for any number of pictures. Firstly, can we rigorously prove why 9 must be the absolute minimum?  I can't seem to generalise this problem to find a function $f(n)$ that determines the minimum number of tacks needed for $n$ pictures.
Attempting this ( trying to spot a pattern )
Simple cases. A single picture needs $4$ tacks. Two need $6$ tacks. Three needs $8$ tacks. Four needs $9$ tacks. Five needs $11$ tacks. Six needs $12$ tacks. Although the pattern seems regular, is it possible to write this as a function? I am stuck.

Hint: Each time you add a picture, you need only 1 or 2 more tacks. For what values does it only increase by 1? Why?

https://oeis.org/A080037

I will make the simplifying assumption that each picture is hung in a cell of a square grid. Or to put it another way, we identify a set of lattice points (points with integer coordinates in some Cartesian coordinate system) and place each corner of each picture on a lattice point.
For very large $n$, we might expect that the number of tacks per picture is going to be approximately $1$ because each picture requires four tacks to hold it but one tack can help hold up four pictures.
Another way to think of it is that in an array of pictures that is very tall and very wide, most of the tacks are on the inside of the array and we can account for all of those tacks by associating each tack with the picture whose upper left corner the tack attaches. So that's $n$ tacks for $n$ pictures, plus some extra tacks at the edge of the array that are not at the upper left corner of a picture.
For a more exact count, replace each tack by four "quarter-tacks". One quarter-tack can hold exactly one corner of one picture, but whenever you attach any corner of any picture you have to use four quarter-tacks around that point. If you have four pictures meeting at one point then each quarter-tack holds one corner of one picture,
but if only three pictures meet at that point you have three quarter-tacks holding corners of pictures and one quarter-tack that is "wasted".
When you have just two pictures meeting at a corner you "waste" two quarter-tacks and when you have a corner of a picture with no other pictures meeting at that corner you must "waste" three quarter-tacks.
The total number of tacks is exactly $1/4$ the total number of quarter-tacks.
For each picture that is hung, there are exactly four quarter-tacks that are devoted to holding up that picture. So the problem now is just to count the number of "wasted" quarter-tacks.
Assume the pictures are hung using the minimum number of tacks.
The pictures cover a region of a plane.
We can first of all suppose that there are no "holes" in the region. If there were a hole, we could find a place in the boundary of that hole where three pictures meet and we could find a picture on the outer boundary of the plane that has an isolated corner (where no other pictures meet). Move the picture on the outer boundary to the place in the hole where the three pictures meet. Three corners of the moved picture can be attached by tacks already on the boundary of the hole, and you can use the tack from the isolated corner to attach the fourth corner of the moved picture if there is not a tack there already. Continue doing this until all holes are filled. Now you have the same number of pictures hung with the same (or smaller) number of tacks, so if there's an optimal configuration with a hole there's an optimal configuration with no hole.
Since there are no holes, the boundary of the region is just one closed curve.
("Curve" in the sense that it's a path in the plane; it actually turns at $90$-degree corners.)
Trace that boundary counter-clockwise around the region (so as you travel along the boundary, there's always a picture on the left side of your path),
starting somewhere in the middle of an edge of a picture.
Every time you pass straight across a point where two pictures meet, you pass two wasted quarter-tacks on the right. Every time you turn $90$ degrees to the right you pass one wasted quarter-tack on the right. Every time you turn $90$ degrees to the left you pass three wasted quarter-tacks on the right.
(Note that this assumes only that the pictures are hung with corners on lattice points, not that the region covered by the pictures is rectangular.)
Stop when you reach your starting point. Now the number of wasted quarter-tacks you have passed is two quarter-tacks for every unit of distance traveled,
minus one quarter-tack for each right turn, plus one quarter-tack for each left turn.
The number of left turns is four greater than the number of right turns, so you have passed $2L + 4$ wasted quarter-tacks, where $L$ is the length of the boundary in units of picture-widths.
The optimal number of tacks to hang $n$ pictures is therefore achieved when you minimize the length $L$ of the boundary of the region covered by the $n$ pictures.
The total number of tacks used is then $f(n) = n + \dfrac L2 + 1$.
Let $h$ be the height and $w$ the width of the region covered by the pictures.
To go around the boundary you have to go up $h$ units and down $h$ units (possibly with other moves in between); you also have to go right $h$ units and left $h$ units.
So $L \geq 2h + 2w$.
Now consider the possible ways that we could have $L > 2h + 2w$. This can only happen if we "backtrack" while traveling along the boundary from one extreme (lowest, highest, leftmost, or rightmost point) to the opposite extreme.
In order to do that we need to have some extra turns, in particular extra right turns, and I claim (but will not prove) that we can "fill in" the concave regions created by these turns while hanging the same number of pictures with the same or fewer tacks much as we can fill in holes.
So we can hang $n$ pictures with a minimum number of tacks in such a way that
$L = 2h + 2w$.
The total number of tacks used is therefore $f(n) = n + h + w + 1$.
It's not hard then to show that if $n$ is a perfect square, the optimal arrangement is to put all the pictures in a square region with $h = w = \sqrt n$.
Then $$f(n) = n + 2\sqrt n + 1 = (\sqrt n + 1)^2.$$
Now consider $n = m^2 + 1$ for integer $m$. The minimum value of $h + w$ then is
$2m + 1$ (either $h = m+1$ and $w = m$ or vice versa).
But also $h + w = 2m + 1$ for any $n$ such that $m^2 < n \leq m^2 + m$.
For these values of $n$,
$$f(n) = n + 2m + 2 = n + 2\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor + 2 = n + 2\lceil\sqrt n\rceil.$$
For $n > m^2 + m$ we can no longer fit the pictures in an $m \times (m+1)$ rectangle.
So we have to increase $h + w$ again. But for $m^2 + m < n \leq (m + 1)^2$ we can fit the pictures inside a square of side $m + 1$, so for these values of $n$,
$$f(n) = n + 2m + 3 = n + 2\lceil\sqrt n\rceil + 1.$$
We can combine the last case with the case where $n$ is a perfect square and have only two cases:
$$
f(n) =
\begin{cases}
n + 2\lceil\sqrt n\rceil & \text{if $m^2 < n \leq m^2 + m$ for some integer $m$}, \\
n + 2\lceil\sqrt n\rceil + 1 & \text{otherwise}. \\
\end{cases}
$$

I think it can be somehow linked to the fact that a certain number of sides can be formed into one. This is at intersection points. It might help to think of how to get the most "corners" with each tack. That would mean finding the most efficient layout for each n.
For perfect squares the best layout would be to have them in a square, since tacks are more efficiently used when they pin down four corners. The first thing that comes into mind when I see $f(4)=9$ is what happens when there are a perfect square amount of pictures. The most "efficient" layout would be to organise them in a square with $\sqrt{n}$ amount of sides. This is true because the amount of tacks would be minimised when each tack is covering four corners. The equation would be $f(n)=(\sqrt{n}+1)^2$ for only perfect squares.
Let me break it down:
Since it is a square, the number of tacks needed in total is the number of tacks needed to pin down each side squared. The number of tacks is $\sqrt{n}+1$ because both ends would have two tacks needed. It will always be like this. Now we can square it based on what I have proven earlier.
This only works for primes, not generalised throughout all integer number of paintings. It is also not much of a rigorous proof which you can expand on.
For other numbers, it might be the closest factors to the "middle" (worded badly). Take 6 for example. The best arrangement would be 2x3, which requires 12 tacks. The factors of 6 are 1,2,3, and 6. 2 and 3 are the two closest numbers to the middle. What about 8? its factors are 1,2,4,8 but and 2,4 are the closest numbers to the middle. This section is just a thought. It can probably be generalised.
This problem is really similar to another problem where you try to maximise the area of a rectangle given its perimeter (or the other way around). The best way to do this is to find the factors, and find the two factors closest to the "middle." The shape with the largest perimeter given its area $A$ would be a rectangle with side $A$ and 1. Since the area and the number of tacks needed in this problem are very closely related, this could be a direction toward the solution to this problem.
